# Local representation $f(z_{0})=w_{0}$ and the open mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a non-constant analytic function on a domain $D$ with $f(z_{0})=w_{0}$. I want to show that $f(z)-w_{0} = (z-z_{0})^{n}k(z) = g((z − z_{0})^{n}) = (h(z − z_{0}))^{n}$ with $k,g,h$ analytic and $k(z_{0})\neq{0}, g'(z_{0})\neq{0}$ and $h'(z_{0})\neq{0}$ (where $n$ is the order of the zero at $w_{0}$). Then I need to use these to prove the open mapping theorem.

At this point I have as tools the Cauchy integral formulas, Morera's and Goursat's theorem, results about power series, the power series representation of holomorphic functions and the fact that an analytic function that is not identically zero, then the zeros of the function are isolated. I do not have the maximum principle yet.

Showing $f(z) − w_{0} = (z-z_{0})^{n}k(z)$ is straightforward but I'm having trouble getting the other representations. Also I tried to prove the other part assuming the results but couldn't really get started.

Also on a non-related subject: I believe that there is a theorem that states if $f'(z_{0})={0}$, then $f$ is not one to one at that particular point. Why is this so and where can I find a reference for this (is this obtained by considering the behavior of the function $|f_{}(z)|$? )

Comment: You can't in general get $f(z) - w_0 = g((z-z_0)^n)$. Consider $f(z) = z^2+z^3$; $g(z^2)$ is an even function, $f$ isn't.

Comment: Can you show the existence of an $n$-th root of $k$ in a neighbourhood of $z_0$? That would give you $h$.

Comment: OK. When can you get $f(z)-w_{0}=g((z-z_{0})^{n})$ then? And I'm not sure how to obtain the result you mentioned or why it would give you $h$. Sorry, I'm really not sure what to use and how to approach the problem here.

Comment: You can write $f(z) - w_0 = g((z-z_0)^n)$ if and only if in the power series expansion of $f$ he only nonzero coefficients correspond to multiples of $n$. And for the other thing, $h(z) = (z-z_0)\sqrt[n]{k(z)}$.

Comment: Wouldn't taking $n^{\text{th}}$ roots mess with the domain in which $h$ needs to be defined?

Comment: You can only write $f(z) - w_0 = h(z-z_0)^n$ in some neighbourhood of $z_0$ (that depends on $f$) anyway, in general not in the full domain of $f$. If that happens to be possible, $$\frac{h(z-z_0)}{z-z_0}$$ is an $n$-th root of $k$ throughout $D$. But the above shows that you can define such a $h$ precisely in every domain where you can define a holomorphic $n$-th root of $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take $z_0=w_0=0$ to simplify writing. This merely shifts the picture. The required representations are

$$f(z)  = z^n k(z) = g(z^n) = (h(z))^{n}$$

You have the first representation already.

#### Second representation

is in general impossible to achieve.  A necessary condition for function $f$ to be written as $g(z^n)$ in a neighborhood of $0$ is: $$f(ze^{2\pi i/n})=f(z)\tag{1}$$  This is  because both $z$ and   $ze^{2\pi i/n}$ give the same value when plugged into $g(z^n)$.

The condition (1) is also sufficient. Indeed, writing $f(z)=\sum c_k z^k$ we see from (1) that  $c^ke^{2\pi ik/n}=c_k$. Hence, $c_k=0$ unless $n$ divides $k$. Now you can write 
$$f(z) = \sum_j c_{nj}z^{nj} =g(z^n)$$
where $g(w)=\sum_j c_{nj} w^j$.

#### Third representation

can be obtained from the first. You should know  something about the principal branch of the root function $z^{1/n}$: namely, that such a thing is defined on $\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$ by $re^{i\theta}\mapsto r^{1/n}e^{i\theta /n}$.

Write $f$ as $k(0)z^n (k(z)/k(0))$. 
Pick $r>0$ such that $|k(z)/k(0) -1 |<1$   when $|z|<r$. This guarantees that $k(z)/k(0)$ is in the domain of the principal branch of the root function. Use the principal branch to define  $\psi(z)=(k(z)/k(0))^{1/n}$. Now you can write 
$$f(z) = (c z \psi(z))^n$$ where $c$ is any number such that $c^n=k(0)$.

#### Open mapping theorem

Here is an approach using the first representation. Fix $r>0$ such that $k(z)\ne 0$ for  $|z|\le r$. 
We have
$$\begin{split}\int_{|z|=r} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz 
&=\int_{|z|=r} \frac{nz^{n-1} k(z) + z^n k'(z) }{z^nk(z)}\,dz
\\&=n \int_{|z|=r} \frac{1}{z}\,dz+ n \int_{|z|=r} \frac{k'(z)}{k(z)}\,dz
\\&=2\pi in \end{split}\tag{2}$$
where $\int_{|z|=r} \frac{k'(z)}{k(z)}\,dz=0$ because $k'/k$ is holomorphic in $|z|\le r$. Suppose there is a sequence $w_n\to 0$
such that $f$ does not attain the value $w_n$ in $|z|\le r$. Then 
$$\int_{|z|=r} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-w_n}\,dz =0 \tag{3}$$ for each $n$. But as $n\to\infty$, the integral (3) converges to integral (2), because
the integrand converges uniformly on $|z|=r$. Contradiction.